# ActiveMQ fails to start (EOFException: null)

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm having issues start my spring web app with camel and ActiveMQ.

The particular error I'm getting is not very descriptive:

```
16:18:53.552 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.a.b.BrokerService - Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([activemq.myworkingdomain.com, ID:Ricardos-MacBook-Air.local-65257-1453738732697-0:2], {})
java.io.EOFException: null
at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v11.SubscriptionInfoMarshaller.looseUnmarshal(SubscriptionInfoMarshaller.java:133) ~[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.doUnmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:366) ~[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:277) ~[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBTopicMessageStore$1.execute(KahaDBStore.java:755) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
at org.apache.kahadb.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:769) ~[kahadb-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBTopicMessageStore.getAllSubscriptions(KahaDBStore.java:749) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBTopicMessageStore.<init>(KahaDBStore.java:663) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore.createTopicMessageStore(KahaDBStore.java:920) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBPersistenceAdapter.createTopicMessageStore(KahaDBPersistenceAdapter.java:100) ~[activemq-core-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
```

I'm sticking with java and simple spring stuff no xml:

```
@Bean
public CamelContext camelContext() {
    final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent());

    try {
        CamelConfigurator.addRoutesToCamel(camelContext);
        camelContext.start();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to start the camel context", e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("Started the Camel context and components");
    return camelContext;
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent() {
    final ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration());
    activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);
    activeMQComponent.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
    return activeMQComponent;
}

@Bean
public JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration() {
    final JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(pooledConnectionFactory());
    jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
    return jmsConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
    final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(
            activeMQConnectionFactory());
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(MAX_CONNECTIONS_TO_POOL_FACTORY);
    // pooledConnectionFactory.start();
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, activeMQBrokerURL);
}
```

I've been trying to change the order in which things load also the routes and what's included in them, deleting the kahadb local folder but nothing seems to work or even point me in the right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace shows that your application in using

- activemq-client-**5.13.0**
- activemq-core-**5.7.0**

I am pretty sure that the version mismatch is responsible for this error.

Can you just import **activemq-all 5.13.0** and try again?

Comment: Thanks a million. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace, seems like you are experiencing issues with KahaDB (the persistence engine by default for Apache ActiveMQ).

I believe KahaDB has a bug within it and you can find information about it on the [Apache issues Web Page](https://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/AMQ-2935)).

I had this issue once, but it strange since it seems like it happens at random, sometimes it works, sometime it fails.

I managed to fix this issue by choosing a different persistence engine for ActiveMQ. Maybe you can give it a try and tell me if it works for you. Hope this information can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now since I also intend to use a shared persistent db it has to be done. I'll update this reply if it works.